# Rename the file using sed or mv command

Tags: bash

Can you please some suggest how to rename the file name using first letter of string for example this is the file i'm having in my Linux box apache-tomcat-8.2.1.

```
mv apache-tomcat-8.2.1 apache
```

this will change as per the my requirements. but in future if same line will be added inside the shell script during the time my tomcat version may be different. So here the questions is how to change the file name using first letter, like

```
mv ^a apache 
# or
sed 's/source_file/destination_file'
```

can you please some one help me how to achieve this using one command, thanks.

Comment: Did you try to press `TAB` after `mv a` ?

Answer (score 1):

If there's **only one** file, you can use [`a*`](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm), which means, all files begin with "a":

```
mv a* apache
```

But note that if there is more than one file that begins with "a", this won't work as expected.

Comment: Hi Maroun, Thanks lot your solution is perfect for me.